# XMPP (smack) in android gives "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server." 

Tags: android

I have created simple chat application using smack api.i can able to chat well.but sometimes the connection to the server is disconnected and following error is thrown.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not
>   connected to server.

how to reconnect to server again?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to same user already logged in another apps.

Answer (score 1):

**java.lang.IllegalStateException**: **Not connected to server** - is thrown in multiple senarios. One such case is while trying to login to an xmpp server as follow:

......
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                        new ConnectionConfiguration(host, port, service);

```
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
                connection.connect();
                connection.login(username, password);
```

......

Check out smack javadoc [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Connection.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) 
**Reason as given in above link**: if not connected to the server, or already logged in to the server

If you are trying to connect to a local xmpp server from an android client, this [link](http://im-a-developer-too.blogspot.ca/2014/04/creating-android-xmpp-client-using.html) could be very helpful